# I can't add Authorization Bearer token to newtwork layer which is created using Moya in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, moya

I make network layer using Moya.I have added bearer access to Header and showing me in log "Personal access client not found. Please create one"

here is my code :

For Service API

```
enum Service {

case addProperty(property_type_id:Int,property_category_id:Int,
user_id:Int,property_name:String,address: String,description:
String,price:Int,city_id:Int,area_id:Int)
                   }

extension Service:TargetType,AccessTokenAuthorizable {
 var baseURL: URL {
        return URL(string: Constant.Url.baseUrl)!
       }

var path: String {

switch self { 
     case .addProperty(_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _):
            return "/add"
          }
    }

 var method:Moya.Method {
      switch self { 
         case .addProperty(_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _):
                return .post
      }
}

var sampleData: Data {
      switch self {  
         case .addProperty(_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _):
                 return "{'phone':'page'}".data(using: .utf8)!
      }
}

var task: Task { 
       switch self {  
                  case .addProperty(let property_type_id, let property_category_id, let user_id, let property_name, let address, let description, let price, let city_id, let area_id):
            
            var params = [String:Any]()
            params["property_type_id"] = "\(property_type_id)"
            params["property_category_id"] = "\(property_category_id)"
            params["user_id"] = "\(user_id)"
            params["property_name"] = "\(property_name)"
            params["address"] = "\(address)"
            params["price"] = "\(price)"
            params["city_id"] = "\(city_id)"
            params["area_id"] = "\(area_id)"
            
            var formData = [MultipartFormData]()
            for (key, value) in params {
                if let imgData = value as? Data {
                    formData.append(MultipartFormData(provider: .data(imgData), name: key, fileName: "testImage.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg"))
                } else {
                    formData.append(MultipartFormData(provider: .data("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!), name: key))
                }
            }
            return .uploadMultipart(formData
        }
    }

var headers: [String : String]? { 
            switch self { 
                case .addProperty(_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _):
                return ["Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                            "Authorization": "Bearer+\(Constant.accesstoken.token)"]
            }
    }

 var authorizationType: AuthorizationType? {
          switch self {
                  case .addProperty(_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _):
                   return .bearer
             }
     }
}
```

here is network manager :

```
protocol Networkable {
     var provider: MoyaProvider<Service> { get }
    
 func addProperty(property_type_id:Int,property_category_id:Int,user_id:Int,property_name:String,address: String,description:String,price:Int,city_id:Int,area_id:Int,completion:@escaping (Data?)->Void)
}

class NetworkManager:Networkable {

          static let shared = NetworkManager()
          private init() {}
         var provider = MoyaProvider<Service>()

func addProperty(property_type_id: Int, property_category_id: Int, user_id: Int, property_name: String, address: String, description: String, price: Int, city_id: Int, area_id: Int, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        provider.request(.addProperty(property_type_id: property_type_id, property_category_id: property_category_id, user_id: user_id, property_name: property_name, address: address, description: description, price: price, city_id: city_id, area_id: area_id)) { (result) in
            self.requestCompletion(result: result) { (data) in
                completion(data)
            }
        }
    }


    //MARK: For The Completion
    func requestCompletion(result:Result<Moya.Response, MoyaError>,completion:@escaping (Data?)->Void){
        switch result {
            
        case let .success(response):
            do {
                completion(response.data)
            } catch let err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil)
            }
            
        case let .failure(error):
            print("error is : \(error.errorDescription)")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Still I am getting Error "message": Personal access client not found. Please create one."

How can i add Authorization token or is there anything need to add in header .backend Php laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I've stored the `OAuthToken` in `UserDefaults`. Now
alter `provider` with

```
let provider = MoyaProvider<Service>(plugins : [AccessTokenPlugin { _ in UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "OAuthToken") as! String }])
```

Hope this works.!